# How does this table have too many unprocessed floats

Tags: tables, floats, tabularx

```
    % Table generated by Excel2LaTeX from sheet 'Sheet1'
%\begin{changemargin}{0.5cm}{0.5cm} 

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[htbp]
    \centering
    \caption{Pearson Correlation Table for Multivariate Analysis (\textit{continued})}
    \begin{tabular}{ll|rrrrrrrrr}
        \multicolumn{2}{l}{} &
\multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{dbacba}} &
\multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{cbagdp}} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{dbagdp}} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{fdgdp}} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{ll\_usd}} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{xregme}} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{xregcon}} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{overhead}} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{llgdp}} \\ 
\midrule
 \multirow{19}[0]{*}{} & \textbf{nim}&
 -.193 & .177  & -.060 & -.014 & .380  & .034  & -.263 & .416  & -.127 \\
  &\textbf{costinc}&-.222 & .289  & .202  & -.036 & -.472 & -.200 & .444  & .296  & .066 \\
    & \textbf{zscore}&.458 & -.563 & -.096 & .009  & .094  & -.205 & .317  & -.467 & -.010 \\
      &\textbf{offdep}&-.548 & .318  & -.535 & -.709 & -.185 & -.320 & -.184 & .272  & -.636\\
      & \textbf{nplgln}&.040  & -.301 & -.239 & -.304 & .060  & -.067 & -.414 & -.195 & -.354 \\
  & \textbf{liqdty} &-.077 & -.131 & -.668 & -.446 & -.031 & -.401 & .169  & -.107 & -.535 \\
  & \textbf{GDP} &.014 & .078  & -.214 & -.117 & -.258 & -.102 & .404  & .207  & -.156 \\
  & \textbf{infltn}&-.020  & -.179 & -.594 & -.432 & -.062 & -.303 & .043  & -.105 & -.535 \\
  & \textbf{fdi}&-.107  & -.040 & -.241 & -.130 & .157  & -.013 & -.218 & -.103 & -.195 \\
  & \textbf{bcbd}&.392 & -.383 & .633  & .284  & -.067 & .703  & -.604 & -.365 & .486 \\
  & \textbf{dbacba}&\textbf{1.000}  & -.918 & .432  & .519  & .399  & .707  & -.387 & -.759 & .550 \\
  & \textbf{cbagdp}&-.918  & \textbf{1.000} & -.252 & -.272 & -.341 & -.564 & .449  & .836  & -.332 \\
  & \textbf{dbagdp}&.432 & -.252 & \textbf{1.000} & .876  & .340  & .638  & -.371 & -.357 & .941 \\
  & \textbf{fdgdp}&.519  & -.272 & .876  & \textbf{1.000} & .509  & .607  & -.265 & -.350 & .947 \\
  & \textbf{ll\_usd}&.399 & -.341 & .340  & .509  & \textbf{1.000} & .318  & -.430 & -.352 & .392 \\
  & \textbf{xregme}&.707   & -.564 & .638  & .607  & .318  & \textbf{1.000} & -.739 & -.454 & .678 \\
  & \textbf{xregcon}&-.387  & .449  & -.371 & -.265 & -.430 & -.739 & \textbf{1.000} & .435  & -.311 \\
  & \textbf{overhead}&-.759  & .836  & -.357 & -.350 & -.352 & -.454 & .435  & \textbf{1.000} & -.429 \\
  & \textbf{llgdp} &.550  & -.332 & .941  & .947  & .392  & .678  & -.311 & -.429 & \textbf{1.000}
\end{tabular}%
\label{tab:addlabel}%
\end{table}%


\end{document}
```

Comment: too many unprocessed floats mean you have too many tables that do not fit not that there is anything wrong with that table, It also means that you have an old (2014 or older)  version of latex

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't.

If you add a working header e.g.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}  

\usepackage{booktabs,multirow}
```

it compiles without errors. The too many floats must be somewhere else in your document.

Try to cook your file down to a [MWE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that)

Comment: not necessarily somewhere else, that table may be the table that triggers the too many floats error, which does not imply that there is anything wrong with that table.

Comment: Here's one of it error message: "Too many unprocessed floats. \begin{table}[htbp]", "Undefined control sequence. \begin{table}[htbp]", "Argument of \@xnext has an extra }. \end{table}",